# Potential energy with Taylor series for particle

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation

I have been doing the following problem:

Imagine we got a particle in $U(x)$ field and we need to consider the motion of the particle near $x=a$. It says to use Taylor series for $U(x)$

$U(x) = U(a) + U'(a)(x-a) + \frac{1}{2}U''(a)(x-a)^2 + ...$

The problem goes to ask to consider cases: $U'(a) = 0$ and $U'(a) \neq 0$, $U''(a) \neq 0$. Note that it exactly mentions cases like that word by word, so I don't know which cases I need to consider.

When I treat $U'(a) \neq 0$, I arrived at the correct answer but only when I treated $U''(a) = 0$, but when I treat $U'(a) = 0$, I arrive at the correct answer when $U''(a) \neq 0$.

I don't get it. Why should I make $U''(a) = 0$ when doing $U'(a) \neq 0$ case and not neglect when I do $U'(a) = 0$. The book mentions the cases in this exact order: $U'(a) = 0$ and $U'(a) \neq 0$, $U''(a) \neq 0$

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U'(a)=0$ then the leading term is $\frac12 U''(a)(x-a)^2$ so the potential is harmonic around $x=a$.

If $U'(a)\ne 0$ and $U''(a)\ne 0$, then set $(x-a)=\xi$ and observe that
\begin{align}
U''(a)(\xi-b)^2=U''(a)b^2-2b U''(a)\xi+ U''(a)\xi^2
\end{align}
contains a term linear in $\xi$ so you can then rewrite your potential choosing $b$ so
$$
U(a)+U'(a)(x-a)+\frac12 U''(a)(x-a)^2\sim V_0+V_2\xi^2\, ,
$$
eliminating the linear term and leaving again only the quadratic term.

Comment: Interesting thing is the book doesn't understandably say which cases to consider exactly. Does it mean that i should treat $U''(a) \neq  0$ for both ?

Comment: Well, the linear case is easy by itself so yes I read it as $U''(a)\neq 0$ always but then a first case with $U'(a)=0$ and a second case with $U'(a)\ne 0$.

Comment: So we got not 2 but 4 cases. 1) $U'(a) = 0 U''(a) \neq 0$ 2) $U'(a) = 0 U''(a) = 0$ and $U'(a) \neq 0 U''(a) = 0$, $U'(a) \neq 0 U''(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the confusion here.  Case 2) means your oscillator is cubic and the problem is a variation on the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation) for this there is no "easy" solution: unless your instructor is a sadist we can exclude this case.  Otherwise all the other cases can be brought back to a linear or quadratic potential.